# Using Excel SaveAs command in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have done research and found very little on this topic. I made a excel macro to save a file online, but wanted to port the code over into Access to have all the code in one place (I was calling the Excel Macro through Access).
Here is the Excel Macro.

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone



ActiveWorkbook.ServerViewableItems.DeleteAll
ActiveWorkbook.ServerViewableItems.Add ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "website" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

It works in Excel. When I move it over to Access, I changed the code a bit.

```
Dim objWorkbook As Object
Dim sourcefilepath As String

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.Application.Visible = False


objXL.displayalerts = False
'objXL.Application.Run ("SharepointUpload")'
objXL.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
objXL.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

objXL.ActiveWorkbook.ServerViewableItems.DeleteAll
objXL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    "website" _
    , FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False

objWorkbook.Close
objXL.Quit

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objXL = Nothing
```

However, I keep getting run-time error '1004' SaveAs method of Workbook class failed. I am thinking it is a way of setting variables for Excel in Access. Any help is appreciated

Comment: these `xlExcel12` wont exist I think.  You need to bring in the excel library in to access' references in vba

Comment: I changed it back to xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled because the workbook is xlsm and changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. How silly of me!

Comment: If you're using the early-bound enum types, then why are you coding against a late-bound `Object` instead of an actual `Excel.Application` instance? You'll get better run-time performance, and design-time IntelliSense and compile-time validation. Late-bound code happily compiles `objXL.IDontExistAndWillOnlyBlowUpAtRuntime`.

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: @FamousFrik -- is this question now resolved?  You just had to add a reference?